# Changing Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wish to construct a random string consisting of only alphabetical characters. This is the code I have so far:

```
letters :: String
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

{- | Generates any lower case alpha character.
-}
lowerAlpha :: Gen Char
lowerAlpha = oneof (map return letters)

getString :: Int -> String
getString 0 = []
getString n = lowerAlpha : getString (n - 1)
```

getString is passed a random Int between 1 and 25. Because lowerAlpha returns a Gen Char getString wont work as it expects a Char in order to build a String. Is there a way to change a Gen String to a String? This is the line of code where the problem occurs - `getString n = lowerAlpha : getString (n - 1)`

Comment: If you could please make that a [MCVE]. It's a bit annoying when we need to guess what `Gen` and `oneof` are.

Comment: Is this a question about Quickcheck in particular, or about randomness in general?

Comment: Since `Char` is an instance of `Enum`, you can write `letters = ['a'..'z']` to avoid having to type out all the lowercase letters by hand.

Comment: @Michael  It's about Quickcheck.

Comment: @chepner, one should avoid `oneOf` here. It will surely be faster to use `choose ('a', 'z')`.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way to change a `Gen String` to a `String`?

No, emphatically not. For some reason, people coming from other programming languages always seem to think “they're both string-kinds of types, so surely they're convertible”. Nope! `Gen String` is something completely, fundamentally different from `String`. The latter is just a plain data value – a list of characters. But `Gen String` is a generator, an *action* that generates strings. Assuming this can be converted to a string is like assuming a cow can be converted to a milk bottle.

The correct thing is for course for `getString` to also have a `Gen` type, because *generating* strings is what it does.

```
getString :: Int -> Gen String
```

The question is how to *implement* that. Well, it's guessworking because you didn't specify what `Gen` is exactly, but such type constructors in Haskell are usually [applicative functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative). That allows you to write

```
getString 0 = pure []
getString n = (:) <$> lowerAlpha <*> getString (n - 1)
```

As gallais remarks, this can also be written shorter as

```
getString n = replicateM n lowerAlpha
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning `replicateM`.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are looking for [`vectorOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:vectorOf), i.e.:

```
import Test.QuickCheck

getString :: Int -> Gen String
getString n = vectorOf n lowerAlpha
```

To actually generate a random string you can use [`generate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:generate) (requires the IO-monad):

```
main = do
  generate (getString 25) >>= putStrLn
```

or just from the GHCI repl:

```
ghci> generate (getString 25)
"siebrxrlvuuxdvhqwcfykqwdc"
ghci> generate (getString 3)
"rcv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your assistance. This is what I came up with. Works well. `str <- listOf (choose ('a','z'))`